# How can I record audio into existing audio file with append mode?

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

How can I record audio into existing audio file with append mode, which contains both audio recording in single file.

Example:

I have recorded 1.amr file. Playing time is 00:30 sec, now I have to record another 00:20 sec but file should be same and next recording should append existing 00:30 sec recording. So now playing time will be 00:50 sec.
Is it possible in Java or Android?
Any library is avaliable for this?

Comment: You pretty much need to decode it to wav and splice the files together, then re-encode.  amr files are compressed, its not normally possible to just append data to a compressed file and get a valid file as a result.  Especially if you want to do more than one format.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will use only one format , for me .wav will work. but how to do it ? you have any code sample or library. Please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to record files separately and then can join them together.

Use RAW AMR format. i.e. set recorder settings to:

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Once you have audio files generated in RAW AMR, you can join these files by striping the first 6 byes of file you are appending. Open the audio files in binary mode for the same.

Comment: Yup @sahaj you are life saver.... solved my problem after 2 days of R&D.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once.. and what i found was.. most of the apps capture the audios separately and then combine then.

Actually, **"You can not do that at recording time"**.

So,

If you have no problem with third party libs... here you can go.

```
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.21'
```

**Code example.**

```
import com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Container;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Movie;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Track;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by crazy_programmer on 9/25/2017.
 */

public class Audio_util {

    private String dest_file_name;

    public Audio_util(String dest_name) {
        dest_file_name = dest_name;
    }


    public String ConcatAudios(File... mp3Files) {

        if(mp3Files == null) return null;

        File mergedFile = new File(dest_file_name);

        for(File fi : mp3Files){
            Log.e("Mod dates",""+fi.lastModified());
        }

        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // sort the array for audio sequence

        if (mp3Files.length > 1) {
            Arrays.sort(mp3Files, new Comparator<File>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                    return Long.valueOf(object1.lastModified()).compareTo(object2.lastModified());
                }
            });
        }
        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        for(File fi : mp3Files){
            Log.e("Mod dates 2nd",""+fi.lastModified());
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        String file_name = null;
        try {
            if (!mergedFile.exists()) {
                mergedFile.createNewFile();
            }
            Movie[] movies = new Movie[mp3Files.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < mp3Files.length; i++) {
                movies[i] = MovieCreator.build(mp3Files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }

            final Movie finalMovie = new Movie();

            List<Track> audioTracks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Movie movie : movies) {
                for (Track track : movie.getTracks()) {
                    if (track.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(track);
                    }
                }
            }

            finalMovie.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));

            final Container container = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(finalMovie);
            FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(mergedFile, "rw").getChannel();
            container.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();

            if (mergedFile.exists() && mergedFile.length() > 1) {
                file_name = mergedFile.getName();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("mp3Files main excpt", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return file_name;
    }


}
```